# UIwebview picture to new view controller

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIWebview displaying my html page with picture links. How can I make it so when the user clicks the link, it brings up a new view controller displaying the html image and have the option to go back to the previous screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure your web view only contains images links then you can make your current view controller implements the UIWebViewDelegate especially:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     // Here you initialized your new view controller from your storyboard and pass the image url to it, and it shall know how to load it in an image view or anything, and you return NO, to stop the web view from loading the request so that the user only sees your links
    SecondViewController* second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondController"];
    second.urlRequest = request;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Of course the above code assumes many things:

You have a property called urlRequest in your SecondViewController class.

You have a navigation controller that contains your FirstViewController.

You are using storyboards and your SecondViewController id is secondController